# Docker Apache Virtualhost

Tags: docker, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to migrate my apps to docker, but with Apache I'm having some troubles. I'm adding my site.conf to apache (this works fine):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com.
        ServerAlias api.example.com

        Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteOptions inherit
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/external/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/external/private.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/external/ca_bundle.crt

        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        ProxyPass / http://example:8090/
        ProxyPassReverse /  http://example:8090/

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteOptions inherit

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to add a new virtualhost with a subdomain the container does not start:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub1.example.com
    ServerAlias sub1.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://myapp2:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://myapp2:8090/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub2.example.com
    ServerAlias sub2.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://myapp2:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://myapp2:8090/

</VirtualHost>
```

I copy the log files from the container to my host machine, but the errors.logs file doesn't show any significant error as to why it won't boot. The docker logs container-name command doesn't help much either.

Any idea of the possible error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I created a new configuration (new_site.conf) and added my virtualhost configuration. Then I enabled it (a2ensite new_site.conf), I restarted the service and everything was still working. I tried to access through the url and it redirected me well to my application.